# Check all values of column

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Let's say I am storing movie names in a column called "title" in a database table.
So "title" will have values like, eg, "where eagles dare", "the social network" etc.

Now if I search on, let's say, "dare where" it should return me "where eagles dare".

What should be the `where` clause here?

Comment: What database? You say "nosql", but you also say "where clause"....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ store tags, if you want to search based on tags ( as is your case ) :
Example document:

```
{ '_id' : 'xxxxxxxxx',
   'movie' : 'where eagles dare'
   'tags' : ['where','eagles','dare']
}
```

Then use $all operator to match all tags,

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all

```
db.movieCollection.find( { 'tags' : { $all: [ 'dare', 'where' ] } } );
```

2/ use regular expressions for this, if you want to search with patterns :

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

```
db.movieCollection.find( { name : { $regex : '.*eagles.*', $options: 'i' } } )
```

will search all movies having "eagle" in them.

Comment: Thanks. this is exactly what i am looking for. your choice of mongodb is perfect. this is what i am using.